# Magento 2 : Product Attribute Rule Conditions

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have added following field in my UI Component Form in a custom module to get the **Product Attributes ** in conditions, but the options given in the drop-down are **Cart Attributes** whereas I need **Product Attributes**!

Here is my code,

```
<fieldset name="conditions">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products with Conditions</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">127</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <container name="conditions_apply_to" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Magento\SalesRule\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Edit\Tab\Conditions</argument>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
</fieldset>
```

How can I change this?

Comment: do you want to display your product custom attribute to product attribute select list?

Comment: Please review this 2 file: `Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Combine` and `Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition`.

Comment: @NikunjVadariya I only need the default  Product attributes provided by magento , no customization.

Comment: Which default attribute you want to add inside product attribute condition?

Comment: @NikunjVadariya go to content->widgets and in widgets options you can see CONDITIONS at the bottom . I need same product attributes

Comment: Please tell where you want to do this customization.

Comment: I do the same thing in my custom form condition.

Comment: In `_prepareForm()` function in block file. Can you tell me what you write in `$renderer` variable?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh this is Ui component form , please re-read the question I am not doing any customization.

Answer (score 2):

You need replace follow lines in file `app/code/Vendor/Rules/Model/Rule.php`

Find this:

```
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
```

Replace with:

```
\Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
\Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule\Condition\ProductFactory $condProdCombineF,
```

Comment: what is the path for /Rules/Model/Rule.php in Magento Core Files?

Comment: You override `rule.php` or not.

Comment: No, not at the moment.

Comment: You want to change in core file first and check it. If working then override it.

Comment: Yes! so where is the actual file in core to this one app/code/Vendor/Rules/Model/Rule.php ?

Comment: In `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule.php`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78630/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-verdu).

Comment: let me know how we can apply our created condition in the frontend

Comment: @divyasekar Please explain clear requirement or else create new question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `SalesRule`, you need to use `CatalogRule`.

You can extends from `\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic`.

You need your conditions class with a constructor and method. This is an example of how it could be:

```
 /**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
 * @param \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset
 * @param array $data
 * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory|null $ruleFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions,
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,
    array $data = [],
    \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory = null
) {
    $this->_rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
    $this->_conditions = $conditions;
    $this->ruleFactory = $ruleFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get(\Magento\CatalogRule\Model\RuleFactory::class);
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
}

/**
 * Handles addition of conditions tab to supplied form.
 *
 * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $model
 * @param string $fieldsetId
 * @param string $formName
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Form
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
protected function addTabToForm($model, $fieldsetId = 'conditions_fieldset', $formName = 'sales_rule_form')
{
    if (!$model) {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $model = $this->ruleFactory->create();
        $model->load($id);
    }
    $conditionsFieldSetId = $model->getConditionsFieldSetId($formName);
    $newChildUrl = $this->getUrl(
        'catalog_rule/promo_catalog/newConditionHtml/form/' . $conditionsFieldSetId,
        ['form_namespace' => $formName]
    );

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');
    $renderer = $this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate(
        'Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml'
    )->setNewChildUrl(
        $newChildUrl
    )->setFieldSetId(
        $conditionsFieldSetId
    );

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        $fieldsetId,
        [
            'legend' => __(
                'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
            )
        ]
    )->setRenderer(
        $renderer
    );
    $fieldset->addField(
        'conditions',
        'text',
        [
            'name'           => 'conditions',
            'label'          => __('Conditions'),
            'title'          => __('Conditions'),
            'required'       => true,
            'data-form-part' => $formName
        ]
    )->setRule(
        $model
    )->setRenderer(
        $this->_conditions
    );

    $form->setValues($model->getData());
    $this->setConditionFormName($model->getConditions(), $formName);
    return $form;
}
```